# Using php to edit CartoDB infowindow?

Tags: carto, php, infowindow

Perhaps a basic question, but can php code be used in editing the CartoDB infowindow HTML? We want to show or hide a category depending on the value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it. Just render the HTML you need in the view and "inject" that code in the visualization infowindow template. For example:

```
...
   layer.infowindow.set('template', document.getElementById('infowindow_template'));
...
```